# Python window sizing in Windows with non default display sizing

Tags: python, windows

I recently purchased a 4K laptop and have run into a problem with window sizing.

I wrote a python application that resizes the window based on the system's resolution. It works fine...except on the 4K laptop.

It does not work here because due to the 4K resolution, everything is far too tiny. So there is a feature in Windows 10 under Settings > Display > "Change the size of text, apps, and other items:" where you can resize things. The recommended value here is 250% as opposed to the normal 100%.

This means the size of the window, which is huge to begin with due to the 4k display, is actually 250% bigger than that due to resizing.

Is there any way to write a python script to work around Windows? Or to exempt Python applications from this Windows feature?

Comment: The only solution I have found so far is to see if the resolution is 3840x2160 and if so, manually set it to some smaller proportion that works for my screen. But this won't scale to other people with different windows enlargements.

Answer (score 0):

Windows will scale any application that is not declared as DPI-aware (either in the manifest, or in the application properties).

If you're working with an exe (either an embedded python instance, or a pyinstaller generated one), you can right click on the exe, go to the Compatibility tab, and check the "Disable DPI scaling" box. You can also adjust the manifest of the exe (however, this is often compiled into the exe, making changing it challenging without special tools, though pyinstaller keeps it seperate). If you can access the manifest, here's info on how to change it:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/09/10/manifest-madness/

If your working with an uncompiled python script, you can call the WIn32 SetProcessDPIAware function with ctypes to do this:

```
from ctypes import *
import [your gui framework]

[your code here]

if __name__ == '__main__':
  windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(c_int(1))
  [rest of your code]
```

The call might throw an HRESULT of access denied (0x80070005) if the python interpreter you're using already declared DPI-awareness in the manifest of the interpreter. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn302122(v=vs.85).aspx for details.

You may want to take a look at these articles on MSDN for more information about creating DPI aware applications (and how to tell Windows about it):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms701681(v=vs.85).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn469266(v=vs.85).aspx